# CentOS 6 - Send user defined command from PHP

Tags: linux, bash, shell, php

I have a web control panel and I need my allow my users to send commands to their application.

I a similar problem to SQL injection.

```
$user_input='good command';
shell_exec('tmux send-keys session1:0 "'.$user_input.'" C-m');
```

This would send the command `tmux send-keys session1:0 "good command" C-m` , which is fine.

But the user could also type some other.

```
$user_input='good command" C-m | rm / | tmux send-keys sessionUserMayNotDoAnyThingIn:0 "some command';
shell_exec('tmux send-keys session1:0 "'.$user_input.'" C-m');
```

This would send the command `tmux send-keys session1:0 "good command" C-m | rm / | tmux send-keys sessionUseerMayNotDoAnyThingIn:0 "some command" C-m`

(That would send 3 commands)

```
tmux send-keys session1:0 "good command" C-m
rm /
tmux send-keys sessionUseerMayNotDoAnyThingIn:0 "some command" C-m
```

So what is the solution for this?

Comment: No user input can ever be trusted.

Comment: @EvanDarwin Will something like \n be possible before the ""

Comment: Of course, in which case it becomes an endless game of you adding regexes and replacements. I would however have you check out http://docker.io/ which doesn't run in tmux sessions but they get their own low-memory "VM" per se.

Comment: @EvanDarwin docker would not fit my needs :( But would it be safe if I did like this `shell_exec('tmux send-keys session1:0 \n"'.$user_input.'\n" C-m');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `escapeshellcmd()` for command escaping (first token) and `escapeshellarg()` for arguments escaping.

Comment: Just to be sure. Is the fully secure? `shell_exec("tmux send-keys -t session:0 ".escapeshellarg($user_input)." C-m");`

Comment: If you should allow only commands (without arguments) you should use only  `escapeshellcmd($user_input)`, but should check if it is an allowed command before.

Comment: If you want to allow arguments, you should first separate the command from arguments and tokenize the source string using spaces, pass first token with `escapeshellcmd()` and `escapeshellarg()` with each argument, then you will make sure a string "; rm -rf /" will be passed as only one argument instead allowing it run as command.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure what you mean. Isn't shell_exec("tmux send-keys -t session:0 ".escapeshellarg($user_input)." C-m"); good enough? If not can you then do an example how to?

Comment: You need to allow user to send just commands (e.g. `whoami`) or commands with arguments (e.g. `ls -l /tmp`)?